# Get list of markers in bounds in React Native

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

How to get list of markers in specific bounds in `react-native-maps`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to `react-native-maps`.

In order to check markers in specific bounds you can use for example [mapbox/cheap-ruler library](https://github.com/mapbox/cheap-ruler). 
The function you are looking for is `insideBBox`

You can also do it in pure javascript

```
if( bb.ix <= p.x && p.x <= bb.ax && bb.iy <= p.y && p.y <= bb.ay ) {
    // Point is in bounding box
}
```

`bb` is the bounding box, (ix,iy) are its top-left coordinates, and (ax,ay) its bottom-right coordinates. `p` is the point and (x,y) its coordinates.

**So:**

1. Loop on your array of markers
2. Use one of the options above (cheap-ruler or pure js)
3. Get the new list of markers inside the bounding box
4. Update your React Native state using `setState`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this